# escpos printer image not getting align to center

Tags: python, escpos

I am using escpos for printing the Token in our Queue managment system python. I  need to put the company logo in header of the token. I am trying to do the same as below.

```
printer.set(align='center')
    #printer.qr("You can readme from your smartphone")
    printer.image("index/index_statics/img/brand/Webp.net-resizeimage.png")
```

But the image is always alignef to left. I have seen many links on the same. but nothing that I can understant. I am very new it. Please help to understand the issue and please help me to resolve the same. The printer is ZKTeco (ZKP8008) termal printer

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ESC/POS question.  Just that the printer can interpret ESC/POS does not mean that escpos is the good category for a framework/library question.